# Crown shape in water waves?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, water

Watching this slow motion [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NF8aQHwcKN0) of waves caused by a droplet falling on water, I am puzzled by the first wave shape.

[image: Picture taken from youtube video]

The first wave rises with circular symmetry as I expected, but is not even in all directions, it rather has peaks with certain angular periodicity, much like a crown. Each of these peaks give rise to small droplets.

After this the outgoing waves move away symmetrically and with constant elevation through all angles.

Is this phenomenon (crown shape) studied and described already? How to explain such angular difference in amplitude, and how come is not present in the following waves?

Comment: "...  unity is said to be the mystery
Mystery of mysteries, the door to all wonders" good question.

Comment: I'm not even going to attempt to answer, but thoughts. The water surface before the event.. probably near perfect flatness, radial symmetry. But the falling drop of water.. probably not so nearly perfect, symmetric, and possibly affected by wind shear.

Comment: I suspect surface tension -- but since people have been studying this at least since the first EGG strobe light was invented,  there is a body of work on hydrodynamics in response to an impulse force.

Comment: Watching the video: the thrown  droplets, from conservation of momentum, deplete from the round shape of the crown. The regularity must come from a circle boundary condition , similar to a circular wave with peaks (crown)troughs where the droplets fly off. The secondary waves do not have enough vertical momentum to break the cohesive forces of water.

Comment: Indeed there is some kind of wave phenomenon around the crown: after the small droplets leave it, the peaks seem to oscillate throughout the circle, which I guess dissipates leaving only the radial growing part alive.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203753/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this phenomenon (crown shape) studied and described already?

[Wetzel (1987)](http://oai.dtic.mil/oai/oai?verb=getRecord&metadataPrefix=html&identifier=ADA188720) describes and tries modeling the splash process, including the crown. (There's a link to the PDF.)

A reference to it may be found on p. 208 of [Surface Waves and Fluxes, Volume II — Remote Sensing, Editors: Geernaert, G.L., Plant, W.J. (Eds.)](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780792308058). ([Google](https://books.google.nl/books?id=kNz6CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA208&dq=%22falling+drop%22+%22crown+shaped%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIk8-H34b-xwIVA5JyCh27pwTr#v=onepage&q=%22falling%20drop%22%20%22crown%20shaped%22&f=false) might show you the preview.)

---

[Crown-forming instability phenomena in the drop splash problem,
Rouslan Krechetnikov, George M. Homsy, 2009 (warning: pdf)](http://www.engineering.ucsb.edu/~rkrechet/PDFs/papers/jcis2009.pdf):

> With the help of a set of experiments and new theoretical un- derstanding we were able to gain new insights into the nature of the instability responsible for the crown spike formation, as well as into the peculiarities of the crown evolution. In particular, we discovered that there are three major types of crowns — axisym- metric, regular, and irregular — and their selection is done at the very early stages of ejecta formation. Through estimates of growth rates and our kinematic measurements, the Richtmyer–Meshkov instability mechanism is found to play a dominant role at short times. The crown dynamics also exhibits a nontrivial bifurcation behavior, which includes frustration and irregular crown phenom- ena.
>   The above observations require new theoretical advances both at the linear and nonlinear levels of description in order to achieve a complete fundamental understanding of the crown formation and a quantitative comparison with experiments.

---

## Additional information from an incomplete review of publications

This phenomenon is very known and still receives attention, as can be seen from the number of recent publications (see below for an incomplete list).

It was first photographed and described in 1908 by A. M. Worthington in his work [A study of splashes](https://archive.org/details/studyofsplashes00wortrich).

The dynamics and relevant physics is clear and checked experimentally. The important elements have been identified and used to clasify the different forms of the phenomenon. For a short covering see this [PSE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156339/when-a-drop-of-water-falls-into-water-where-do-the-splashes-come-from) or this paper that also tries to identify different regimes. That last paper shows that the "crown shape" is formed in the initial state of the collision and that it is at this moment that its features are determined, and hints on the origin being the [Richtmyer-Meshkov instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richtmyer%E2%80%93Meshkov_instability).

A later [paper](http://www.engineering.ucsb.edu/~rkrechet/PDFs/papers/jcis2009.pdf) shows that the phenomenon has several elements in agreement with calculated values from a model based on the [Rayleigh-Plateau instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%E2%80%93Rayleigh_instability).

Finally, after a chase over recently published articles, however an incomplete and inexhaustive one, I have not find a consensus on the origin of the phenomenon, neither a theoretical model that explains it. Below there are some of the articles found:

*Origin of ejecta in the water impact problem

 Krechetnikov, R.  2014 
Physics of Fluids*

*Numerical analysis of droplet impact onto liquid film

 Shetabivash, H., Ommi, F., Heidarinejad, G.  2014 
Physics of Fluids*

*Turbulent mixing driven by spherical implosions. Part 1. Flow description and mixing-layer growth

 Lombardini, M., Pullin, D.I., Meiron, D.I.  2014 
Journal of Fluid Mechanics*

*Stability on time-dependent domains

 Knobloch, E., Krechetnikov, R.  2014 
Journal of Nonlinear Science*

*Splash wave and crown breakup after disc impact on a liquid surface

 Peters, I.R., Van Der Meer, D., Gordillo, J.M.  2013 
Journal of Fluid Mechanics*

Comment: These are very good references to explaining the process of evolution of the ripples. But apparently they assume, as I did, that the "crown" is symmetric. This seems to be irrelevant for describing the further evolution. But I still can't really understand the initial irregularity of the crown.

Comment: Cool! Very specific! I printed it right now and will read it today!

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think when writing the question that 'crown splash in water' was really a thing, so I skipped googling it.

Comment: Do crowns form just for water drops or do they form for any spherical same sized object dropped in water? What if the object is spinning?

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat your answer set me in the right direction, so I will select it. However I will write another one with summary on the info of the articles, that I think will interest others. I will wait a bit so others can see the question.

Comment: from the first link to the study from NAVAL RESEARCH LAB WASHINGTON: "The detailed hydrodynamics of the splash process is not well understood. In fact, the major reference for rain-like splashes remains the mostly descriptive work by Worthington cited aboc" The purpose of that doc is to study the "Electromagnetic scattering from a raindrop splash on a water surface is examined..." because of radar effects. So I do not understand why the doc is linked at all. Pls, read the abstract in the front page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an effect of the interaction between the liquid and the gas surrounding it, though the mechanism is not understood. You can see videos [here](http://nagelgroup.uchicago.edu/Nagel-Group/Splashing.html) of droplets falling in slow motion at atmospheric pressure, and low pressure. The crown vanishes completely at low pressure. The authors of the study claim

> **The mechanism by which the gas affects splashing remains unknown**. Recently, we used high-speed interference imaging to measure the air beneath all regions of a spreading viscous drop.  Although an initial air bubble is created on impact, no significant air layer persists until the time a splash is created. This suggests that splashing in our experimentally accessible range of viscosities is initiated at the edge of the drop as it encroaches into the surrounding gas - not by air trapped beneath the drop at impact.

Comment: I am not able to see the videos. Any recommended codec? I use chrome.

Comment: but the video is about a drop on solid surface,  different boundary conditions.

Comment: firefox ok (quickmovie)

Answer (score 0):

This phenomena appears tp be related to the Saturn's hexagonal aurora (storm, ?) 
[nytimes video](http://www.nytimes.com/video/science/space/100000003031795/storm-chasing-on-saturn.html?action=click&contentCollection=science&module=lede&region=caption&pgtype=article) , [youtube](https://youtu.be/7YJsxDiBobQ?t=97)

As the sphere approaches the surface the air is compressed and it happens a speedy radial exit , that's why with no atmosphere the effect is not present (as seen on the video of the answer of Bardamu).

[explanation on nytimes](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/06/science/space/storm-chasing-on-saturn.html?_r=0)

> In laboratory experiments with rotating fluids, they were able to
>   reproduce the six-sided shape, providing reassurance that there is
>   nothing supernatural going on at Saturn.
>
> Scientists on Earth have been pondering what causes the vortex to take
>   such an unnatural-looking shape.
>
> In **2010, Ana Aguiar of Lisbon Universit**y and colleagues pointed out
>   that the position of the hexagon on Saturn corresponded to the
>   latitude of **a narrow and very speedy jet stream**. They suggested that
>   friction with slower-moving atmosphere on either side of the jet
>   stream would create eddies, miniature hurricanes, that would push the
>   jet stream north and south as it went around the planet, resulting in
>   a wave shape.

A very recent study ["Origin and dynamics of vortex rings in drop splashing"](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2015/150904/ncomms9187/full/ncomms9187.html) (Nature Jul/2015) shows in detail the formation of the vortexes but noting on the crown.

To show the similarity of the crown effect and the Saturn hexagon I toke a [image: snapshots of the crown] from the video linked in the question, [image: and this one]  and from [image: Saturn's hexagon].